# Pandas Groupby with Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe containing addresses, first names, and last names. I want to group records (rows) based on the first 3 characters in either of these three fields.

For examples, if we have

```
| index | address     | first_name | last_name |
|  1    | 1800 St.    | John       | Adams     |
|  2    | 1800 Street | J.         | A.        |
|  3    | Elm St.     | Junhui     | Wen       |
|  4    | NaN         | Jun        | W         |
```

Then

- records 1 and 2 should be grouped together (same 3 characters in address)
- records 3 and 4 should be grouped together (same 3 characters in first name)

In pandas, I know it's possible to do this with one column:

```
data['3_char'] = data['address'].str[:3]
data.groupby('3_char').count().sort_values('index')['index']
```

But how would you go about grouping records together via an OR condition on all three columns?

Comment: This is difficult. With `groupby` each row needs to belong to a single group. Given your logic, it's possible for row 1 and 2 to match on address, then rows 2 and 3 to match on first name. What happens in this case, do we create one big group of all 3, or should row 2 belong to multiple groups?

Comment: Right. In that case, I would put them all in one group since there's a similarity or "link" between all of them. Also, the solution doesn't have to be one nifty Pandas function. I was wondering if there's a way to do this programmatically in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by collapsing the connectivity between 2 columns at a time. First, we create distinct groups for each column separately, then find which labels are connected pair-wise

#### Sample Data

```
       address first_name last_name
0     1800 St.       John     Adams
1  1800 Street        Jun        A.
2      Elm St.     Junhui       Wen
3          NaN         J.         W
4          111        foo     Adams
```

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Label Each column separately
df['g1'] = 'A' + df.groupby(df['address'].str[:3]).ngroup().astype(str)
df['g2'] = 'B' + df.groupby(df['first_name'].str[:3]).ngroup().astype(str)
df['g3'] = 'C' + df.groupby(df['last_name'].str[:3]).ngroup().astype(str)

# Add the `|` condition for groups
for ga, gb in [('g1', 'g2'), ('g2', 'g3')]:
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, ga, gb)
    # Find connections
    grps= [list(x.nodes) for x in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)]
    # Create new unique group id based on above connections
    d = {y: i for i in range(len(grps)) for y in grps[i]}
    # Replace group label so we can do this for the next pass.
    df[gb] = df[ga].map(d)
```

#### Output:

```
       address first_name last_name  g1  g2  g3
0     1800 St.       John     Adams  A1   0   0
1  1800 Street        Jun        A.  A1   0   0
2      Elm St.     Junhui       Wen  A2   0   0
3          NaN         J.         W  A3   1   1
4          111        foo     Adams  A0   2   0
```

The **True** grouping you want is found in `g3`. `g1` contains the grouping based only on address. `g2` is the grouping based on `address` | `first_name` (we can see that the third row was grouped with the first two now). Finally `g3` is the grouping now based on `|` for all 3 columns, and we can see the 5th row was added with the first 3, based on Last Name

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['g1'] = df.groupby(df['address'].str[:3]).ngroup()
df['g2'] = df.groupby(df['first_name'].str[:3]).ngroup()
```

Output:

```
  index      address first_name last_name  g1  g2
0     1     1800 St.       John     Adams   0   1
1     2  1800 Street         J.        A.   0   0
2     3      Elm St.     Junhui       Wen   1   2
3     4          NaN        Jun         W   2   2
```

Comment: Sorry, what do `g1` and `g2` denote? are these two separate groups? how do I interpret these results?

Comment: You have two separate conditions to groupings. According to one condition index 1,2 are in one group (g1 being 0.) Similarly, index 3,4 are in another group (g2 being 2). @meraxes

Comment: Right! How would I go about consolidating the two columns `g1` and `g2`? Essentially, I want just one column, say g = [0, 0, 2, 2]